# Parse.com - iOS push notifications and Unity integration

Tags: unity-game-engine, push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I notice that Parse Unity support still doesn't provide push notification for iOS.

Has anyone implemented a Unity plugin or another solution to support iOS Push Notifications via Parse?

(Cross posted on [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/768343/ios-push-notifications-via-parsecom.html).)

Answer (score 3):

It's actually possible now, using a ParseObject to mock up the ParseInstallation object.

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/gfosco/a3d092651c32ba3385e6

Explanation in the Parse Google Group:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/parse-developers/ku8-r91_o6s/6ioQ9T2TP7wJ

Attach this script to a GameObject, replace the important parts with your own:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;

public class PushBehaviorScript : MonoBehaviour {

    bool tokenSent = false;
    public ParseObject currentInstallation = null;

    void Start () {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("currentInstallation")) {
            string objId = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("currentInstallation");
            currentInstallation = ParseObject.CreateWithoutData ("_Installation", objId);
        }

        if (currentInstallation == null) {
            #if UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_EDITOR
                NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes (RemoteNotificationType.Alert | RemoteNotificationType.Badge | RemoteNotificationType.Sound);
            #endif
        }
    }

    void  FixedUpdate () {
        if (!tokenSent && currentInstallation == null) {
            #if UNITY_IPHONE && !UNITY_EDITOR
                byte[] token   = NotificationServices.deviceToken;
                if(token != null) {
                    tokenSent = true;
                    string tokenString =  System.BitConverter.ToString(token).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                    Debug.Log ("OnTokenReived");
                    Debug.Log (tokenString);
                    ParseObject obj = new ParseObject("_Installation");
                    obj["deviceToken"] = tokenString;
                    obj["appIdentifier"] = "com.parse.unitypush";
                    obj["deviceType"] = "ios";
                    obj["timeZone"] = "UTC";
                    obj["appName"] = "UnityPushTest";
                    obj["appVersion"] = "1.0.0";
                    obj["parseVersion"] = "1.3.0";
                    obj.SaveAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        if (obj.ObjectId != null) {
                            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("currentInstallation", obj.ObjectId);
                        }
                    });
                }
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, is this officially supported or might this change?

Comment: I can create an Installation object follow this code. However, parse still says "No registered devices" when send push.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Can't modify deviceType of installation object, and if not set the saveasync fails with a "file not found". Tried to use this method because my app doesnt create installation object on ios (works fine on android though).

Comment: Please have a look at other answer here. Tested and works

Answer (score 0):

To implement iOS push with parse.com You need to get the token from apple first. Then save Current instalation 
Unity does have this functionality build in now.

```
//push notification
bool tokenSent = false;


void RegisterForPush()
{
    Debug.Log("Register for push");
    tokenSent = false;

    #if UNITY_IOS
    UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.RegisterForNotifications(NotificationType.Alert |
                                                            NotificationType.Badge |
                                                            NotificationType.Sound, true);

    #endif

}


void Update () {

        if (!tokenSent) {
            byte[] token = UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.deviceToken;

            if (token != null) {
                // send token to a provider
                tokenSent = true;
                string hexToken = "%" + System.BitConverter.ToString(token).Replace('-', '%');

                #if UNITY_IOS
                    ParseManager.instance.RegisterForPush(hexToken);
                #endif

            }
        }
}
```

And inside ParseManager (or whatever class you use to manage parse>client communication)

```
public void RegisterForPush(string token) {

    Debug.Log("Parse updating instalation");

    ParseInstallation instalation = ParseInstallation.CurrentInstallation;
    instalation["deviceToken"] = token;
    instalation["user"] = ParseUser.CurrentUser.ObjectId;
    instalation["timeZoneOffset"] = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
    instalation.SaveAsync();

}
```

Tested on Unity 5.1.2 and iOS 8.4